# Internet Forwarding With Qemu?

Tags: internet, connection, kvm-virtualization, forwarding, qemu

I'm using kvm and qemu to run a windows virtual machine, but I'm trying to get internet on that machine. I've been reading about all this bridging and stuff that is done to do that, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way, to just forward my internet connection (since I'm connected on the host machine) through qemu to the guest operating system. Is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the user network emulation, which is slow, but is simple and should be activated by default indeed.

```
qemu -net nic -net user ...
```

This is how it's done.

This solution have some drawbacks:

1. Some protocole (ICMP) can't reach the internet, but tcp and udp can.
2. From the host you can't reach the guest afaik
3. Networking in the is slow compared to bridging

Comment: Thanks for ICMP, because I've started to panic already why there's no ping and all config is fine

Answer (score 0):

No you have to bridge the connection. [Instructions for Linux](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/~djw/qemu.html). [Instructions for FreeBSD](http://wiki.freebsd.org/qemu). 
If you're going to be running this all the time, you might want to just write a quick script to do the steps automatically.